# Adjust relative font size of *all* monospaced text?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, typewriter

By default, LaTeX makes monospaced text rather large relative to the default serif ("roman") text. This is especially pronounced when choosing custom fonts, e.g.

```
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{DejavuSansMono}
```

Is there some way to rescale *just* the monospaced fonts across the document, regardless of the context?

### Example document

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[scale=0.8, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{upquote} % fix rendering of quotes in verbatim context
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newtcblisting{codeblock}{
    arc=2pt,
    listing only,
    boxrule=0pt,
    bottom=-8pt,
    top=-5pt,
    colback=black!5,
    colframe=black!5,
    listing options={
        breaklines=true,
        columns=fullflexible, % needed for copy-pasting
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{black!70},
    },
}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
% \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{DejaVuSansMono}

\begin{document}



\section{Base situation}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Choosing the combination of \verb|fouriernc| the relative font size of inline \verb|\verb| test and inline \texttt{\string\texttt} text is too large. The issue is more pronounced when enabling \verb|DejavuSansMono|, but to a lesser degree present without. Likewise the contents of
\begin{verbatim}
verbatim
environment
\end{verbatim}
and the self-defined

\begin{codeblock}
codeblock
environment
\end{codeblock}
are too large.\footnote{It also should work in \texttt{\string\footnote} context.}
\end{minipage}


\section{Half-fixes}

The issue can be partly solved on a case-by-case basis, but this is undesirable. For instance, setting \verb|\verbatim@font|. 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\verbatim@font{{\scriptsize}\ttfamily}
\makeatother

For demonstration, here \verb|\verbatim@font| includes \verb|\scriptsize|, which does however not affect \texttt{\string\texttt}. This also affects the default
\begin{verbatim}
verbatim
environment
\end{verbatim}
but not the self-defined
\begin{codeblock}
codeblock
environment
\end{codeblock}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\footnote{In a footnote, the sizing would be anyway wrong, because {\csname verbatim@font\endcsname\string\scriptsize} is too large as font size correction for monospaced text here.}
\end{minipage}

As a consequence adjustments of the font size have to made in many different places.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[scaled=0.5]{DejaVuSansMono}` (adapt the value naturally ...)

Comment: note UTF-8 is the default so better to omit `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` or use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` or just use `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` if you need compatibility with old documents using the `utf8x`  configuration.

Comment: latex does not by deafult make the monospace font large, it chooses both fonts at exactly the same nominal design size.  If you choose two font families for tt and rm or rm and sf or whatever, then it is quite common that you need to scale one or the other to mak ethem blend together better,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid you're starting from a false premise. Compare the standard Computer Modern fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Abc \texttt{Abc} Abc

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that the monospaced font is *smaller* than the Roman counterpart. However, several monospaced fonts have a rather large design size.

On the other hand, most font packages allow for a `scale` or `scaled` option and `DejaVuSansMono` is no exception.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{DejaVuSansMono}

\begin{document}

Abc \texttt{Abc} Abc

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not the best match to my eye, but it's personal preference.

Unrelated: the `utf8x` option to `inputenc` refers to an obsolete and unsupported package. Remove the call to `inputenc` (unless you have a very old TeX distribution).